# Utilizing the power of clusters in the context of databases?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, optimization, cluster-computing

I have a 22 machine cluster with a common NFS mount. On each machine, I am able to start a new MySQL instance. I finished creating a table with about 71 million entries and started an `ADD INDEX` operation. It's been more than 12 hours and the operation is still going on. So what I logged onto one of my other machines in the cluster, started a new instance on MySQL daemon on that machine using:

```
mysqld_safe --user=username
```

And then created a MySQL client on the same machine to connect to the database. The problem is, I am using the exact statement I used to start the client on the first machine:

```
mysql --socket=/homes/username/mysql/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock -u root -p
```

I am able to see all the databases and tables from this client as expected (due to the underlying NFS mount). Now, if I want to create a new table or alter a table (other than the one on which the index is being added currently), I have two questions:

1. Is this even the correct way of
   utilizing a cluster? Or rather, assuming that I have a considerable data mining task in front of me, how can I setup MySQL (without root privileges on the cluster that is) to speed up the task?
2. The statement I used to connect to mysql uses the same mysql.sock file as the first machine. What are the implications of this? I mean, will I end up facing any odd situations?
3. Will I have any performance gain or will I end up
   slowing down the indexing operation
   that is taking place on a different
   machine?

Comment: Are you saying you're running several mysql instances, pointing to the same database files on the NFS mount ?

Comment: @nos: Not several as of now, only 2. I never thought it would work thinking that MySQL would throw an error but it let me create an instance.

Comment: Before thinking of clustering database servers, have you analyzed the bottleneck? Are you running out of RAM? Out of CPU or is the problem disk/network performance?

Comment: @Albin: Looking at the output of `top` shows me: `69084  26m 4416 S 11.7  2.6  84:10.43 mysqld` indicating that neither memory or CPU are being used 100% so I'm guessing the problem is with the network but then everything is connected locally. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work stably  mysqld isn't made for this.  Plus, NFS overhead is not favorable.

You probably need to make a bunch of slave mysqld instances and parallelize your client access.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was afraid NFS will be a curse in my scenario.